# Find line with a whitespace at the end and find "spec(test=3)"

Tags: regex, bash, file

I am doing a script which grep a file and find some sentences.

I would like to find all sentences which finish by a whitespace : I do this

```
if [ $FILE -eq 1  ];then                       
      while read line                                         
      do                                                      
              text=$line                                      
              echo $text | grep "(\\s&\\n)$"                 
      done < $1 fi;
```

I would like to find all sentences which this "spec(/*what you want here*/)" : I do this :

```
if [ $FILE -eq 1  ];then                       
      while read line                                         
      do                                                      
              text=$line                                      
              echo $text | grep "if(/(*/))"                 
      done < $1 fi;
```

But all this grep don't work, someone can help me in my regexp ?

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\s\n)` should work to capture lines that end with a space.
For catching the "spec(/what you want here/) you can use:

```
spec\(/.*/\)
```

I don't know why you used `"if"` in your second attempt, and you need to escape the braces (or use double braces) and the star (meaning zero or more times) should be behind the character(s) you want to match, in this case a  `.` for everything.